# How to force compiler error if struct shallow copy?

Tags: go, struct, shallow-copy

I maintain a library where exported struct has fields that should not shallow copy. For example:

```
type Example struct {
    Val    int
    Nums   []int
}
```

As `Nums` is a field of type slice, a shallow copy of a `Foo` instance copies the slice header and allow bugs:

```
foo := Example{Val: 1, Nums: []int{100}}
bar := Example

bar.Nums[0] = 200

fmt.Println(foo.Nums) // [200]
```

I want to prevent code importing the library to shallow copy the struct. Possible solutions:

- constructor that return a pointer, but nothing stops the client from dereference and shallow copy anyway:

```
pfoo := lib.NewFoo() // returns type `*Foo`
foo := *pfoo // now variable foo is type `Foo`
foo2 := foo  // I don't want this
```

- add abundant documentation to the library to discourage shallow copyies. I can also declare all methods in my library that use `Foo`s to require pointer types, to make things safe *on my side*, but again, importer code may write functions that use `Foo` values.
- add a `Clone()` method to `Foo`, but this falls under "documentation" issue: one may not read it.
- add a custom check to `go vet` but this won't result in compiler errors.
- rewrite the library to avoid exposed non-copiable fields
- put up with the possibility of having bugs

However is there another way to force the compiler to throw an error on struct shallow copies?

Comment: You basicaly cannot. Accept it.

Comment: I'd do it the same way it's handled with `sync.WaitGroup`. That is: in documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup

Comment: Dereferencing `New()` values is a very pathological "flaw".  I can't see a reason anyone would do this unless they just don't understand pointers and are taking a wild guess at appropriate usage.

Answer (score 5):

The issue [runtime: add NoCopy documentation struct type?](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8005) addresses this problem.
A [comment on the issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8005#issuecomment-190753527) recommends this solution:

> Note that code that absolutely must opt in to the vet check can already do so. A package can define:
>
> ```
> type noCopy struct{}
> func (*noCopy) Lock() {}
> ```
>
> and then put a noCopy noCopy into any struct that must be flagged by vet.

An Unlock method is also required to trigger the warning.  Here's the complete solution for the example:

```
type noCopy struct{}

func (*noCopy) Lock()   {}
func (*noCopy) Unlock() {}

type Example struct {
    noCopy noCopy
    Val    int
    Nums   []int
}
```

With this change, the `go vet` command prints the warning `assignment copies lock value to y:Example contains noCopy` for the following code:

```
var x Example
y := x
```

[Run the example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/O3Y89hmI9R6).

Document the requirement that the value should not be copied. Provide a `Clone()` method if applications need a deep copy.

The approach does not add to the size of `Example` because the size of a  `struct{}` is zero.

The standard library `sync.WaitGroup` type [uses](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/3463852b7631adbdd65646539fc87d967dcd13e6/src/sync/waitgroup.go#L21) [this approach](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/3463852b7631adbdd65646539fc87d967dcd13e6/src/sync/cond.go#L89-L98).